# Eclipse from 2019 to 2020-3 hangs when saving changes in web.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I modify web.xml but it takes a lot for Eclipse to process the change, if I have changes with collisions in SVN and there are <<< and "mine" tags it is even worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to an open bug in relation with processing the tags, in my case changing the XML header from

> ... xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
> http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd
> http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
> [http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd%22) id="WebApp_ID"
> version="2.4">

to

> ... xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
> [http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd%22) id="WebApp_ID"
> version="2.5">

Solved the problem (also not a good idea to have two schemas from different versions)